# warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in assets/plugins/bootstrap-treeview-master/tests/tests.js

Tags: git, git-add

Estoy creando un repositorio en git con el comando de `git init` y posteriormente `git add`, el problema que tengo es que el `git bash` me muestra un warning que muestro a continuación:

> warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in
>   assets/plugins/bootstrap-treeview-master/tests/tests.js.

Ya leí un poco sobre el warning y coloque la siguiente línea:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf false
```

Pero el mensaje sigue apareciendo. ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pude solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

**git config --global core.autocrlf false**

**git config --global core.safecrlf false**

Answer (score 0):

Este error da porque Unix se representa el final de la línea comoc un avance de línea **LF**.

En Windows, una línea se representa con un Enter  **CR** y un avance de línea LF por lo tanto se tienen que unir los dos para que no de este problema **CRLF**.

Si desea desactivar esta advertencia, escriba esto en la línea de comando git

```
git config core.autocrlf true
```

Si quieres leer leer mas sobre como utilizar este comando te dejo este link de la documentación oficial [git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration#Formatting-and-Whitespace)

Comment: Aún colocando ese comando me sigue mostrando el mismo Warning, enseguida leo el link que me compartiste para poder solucionarlo. Muchas gracias.