# ¿ Cómo agregar una carpeta completa del Working Directory al Staging Area en Git?

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Hola estoy tratando de subir unas carpetas al Staging Area con el comando `git add .` y tambien probe  con `git add -A`   y la consola me lanza el siguiente error, con infinidad de archivos.

> The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
>   warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/align-text/LICENSE.
>   The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
>   warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in node_modules/align-text/README.md.

Las carpetas las copie en el directorio , cortar y pegar.
Por lo que dice , es que cambia de extensión los archivos, pero no llega a subir los archivos de Working a Staging.
Todo esto es porque quiero subir un repositorio GitHub el cual tiene cuatro módulos, cada uno con sus carpetas y archivos.
Lo intente con GitHub Desktop que otras veces me funciono, pero me resulta imposible.
¿ Que puedo hacer para que no salga ese error y poder subir carpetas enteras y luego hacer los commits 
Gracias

Comment: si estas en la rama master ? esos archivos viene de otro repositorio ?

Comment: Las carpetas simplemente leas he pegado en el directorio @JJ , solo quiero subir el proyecto entero a github y hacerlo desde la terminal pues desde Git Desktop me resulta imposible. He creado un proyecto en github, luego le clono a este y añado todos los modulos.

Comment: Por lo general la carpeta `node_modules` la ignoras (se regenera con `npm install`). El warning ese significa que los archivos que  sean commiteados van a ir con el salto de línea de windows ([CRLF](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRLF)), mientras que tu copia local va  a mantener el salto de línea unix(LF)

Comment: Que hago copio todos los modulos y quito las carpetas de node_modules de cada modulo...?? En la aplicacion de escritorio me dan error algunos archivos y no me deja crear el repositorio

Comment: ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/7615/81450 y https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/154675/81450

Comment: Bueno, corrí esos comando y funciono, aunque ya había eliminado las carpetas de node_modules de cada modulo. Gracias @alo Malbarez, si quereis poner como respuesta, gustoso lo aceptare. El proyecto esta creado en linux, y lo estoy intentando subir con windows, de ahi los problemas.

Comment: la pregunta podría llegar a ser un duplicado "conceptual" de las relacionadas, fijate si podes editar la pregunta y contestarla tu mismo con la solución de tal manera que sirva a otros usuarios en el futuro, el estado inicial del repo, la copia, los warnings y luego la solución (son esos detalles lo que sirven)